# Sharing same (.edmx model) in multiple projects

Tags: entity-framework-4, ado.net, model, entity, data-sharing

I have created a database and converted the same in edmx/model in one of my ASP.NET sample projects.
Now I am creating another project in which I want to use the same .edmx/model. I try to copy the edmx model in second project and then adding up(Add existing item),
But the .edmx file is not showing up in the options,but I am getting the designer.cs. Am I am missing something here?
Is it possible to use the same .edmx in more than one project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply place your edmx model and all generated classes to separate assembly and share the assembly.

If you don't see .EDMX in *Add Existing Item* dialog make sure that you don't have filter for code files enabled. You need to show all files or data files to see .EDMX file.

Comment: Thank you so much and now I can add the same.